# How do you identify a metric pipe thread?

Tags: threading

I have a fitting that I think is a metric pipe thread. It is tapered.

I have seen [some charts on the web](https://www.adaptall.com/info-tutorials/identify-metric-threads.php), but they are just for identifying parallel threads, not tapered threads. For example, these charts just have one "outer diameter" listed for the thread, but obviously each thread has a different diameter if the thread is tapered.

In the case of my fitting, it has 5 threads in 9mm or 11/32" which does match the pitch of any pipe thread that I know of.

Comment: One of these? https://www.fittings.space/fittings-by-thread/pipe-thread-adapters.html

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I need a method for identifying the thread. I can't tell if it matches something random on the web just by looking at the picture.

Comment: I take it to the store and contribute to why the nut and bolt isle is always a mess.

Comment: Compare diameter measurement with those in the photos. Sites with p/n’s and dimensions, one has to match ! e.g. M12 M12X1.25 Male 24 Deg Tapered Hole for Compression

Comment: Near the bottom of the linked page, it tells you to "measure the O.D at the third row of threads from the end of the fitting" for tapered threads. That doesn't address your pitch issue, but it might help narrow things down a bit.

Comment: @doug deden I don’t I would trust a diameter measurement as every time I set up our universal machine it is slightly different, in some cases I set it up a little undersized on purpose I think the TPI or threads per inch would be a better indication as those don’t change.